# Android - Firebase | read all child data

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database like this[image]

the Large,Medium and Small can have any number of children ( abc,xyz etc). I want to read all the children of a given node (say small).

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("small");

// Read from the database
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // This method is called once with the initial value and again
        // whenever data at this location is updated.
        Log.i("Info","Data changed"+Long.toString( dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()));

        for (DataSnapshot dis : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for (DataSnapshot vers : dis.getChildren()) {
                String value = vers.getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("debug", "Value is: " + value);
                toaster(value);
            }
        }
    }
```

But I get no output. I can't figure how else to traverse this data.

Please help

Comment: Your code uses `small`, the database has `Small`.  Since Firebase is case-sensitive, the two strings are not the same. If you use the same case in your code it will work. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this you need to change this line:

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("small");
```

with

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("Small");
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry but that did not work. "Small" can have children which in turn can many children. I want to get those values

Comment: While i was reading again your code, i get the mistake. Please see my updated answer. It should be: `database.getReference().child("Small");` Does it work?

Comment: I made the change but I still get no output. and also the getChildren count returns 0!

Comment: No my bad, It worked!

Comment: Ok Sapnesh. Cheers !

Comment: I had made a change to db from firebase console and forgot about it during debugging. Thanks!